# problems in Flickr api tags photo search with AND condition

Tags: python, api, flickr

I am trying to get some photos using :

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html having both the tags:

```
"abc" and "def" using the following code:

import flickr.py
photos = flickr.photos_search(tags= ["abc", "def"], tag_mode = all, per_page=10)
```

but it's returning photos with the OR condition, the tag_mode = all condition is not working

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the method in the flickr.py will use

```
tag_mode=%3Cbuilt-in+function+all%3E
```

making the API not recognized and use the default any method

The root cause should be inside this function:

```
def _doget(method, auth=False, **params):
```

due to the use of **all** which is a keyword in python, urlencode(all) will
convert it to %3Cbuilt-in+function+all%3E

So the solution to your problem is to change

```
photos = flickr.photos_search(tags= ["abc", "def"], tag_mode = all, per_page=10)
```

to

```
photos = flickr.photos_search(tags= ['abc', 'def'], tag_mode = 'all', per_page=10)
```